# Call APIs on web with py-script

Tags: python, pyscript

I try to call an API with http.client th error says that the 'http.client' has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection':

[image: Error]

The code is:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.banxico.org.mx")
payload = ''
headers = {}
conn.request("GET", "/SieAPIRest/service/v1/series/SP68257/datos/2022-11-11/2022-11-11?token=04021aac739b77e232d9670147936836e9e9fc31e08bde26665c0f013df94471", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

The code work well on jupyther notebook, but not in web.

Comment: have you tried the requests library ? https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `http.client` depends on modules such as `ssl` which are not supported when running inside the web browser. Rewrite your code to use supported APIs such as `pyfetch`.